# In IOS how to implement (EULA) when app start first time

Tags: ios, eula

recently i published one of the social network app on apps store and it been rejected two times. the issue is require users to agree to terms (EULA). but i already included (EULA) in the app but it not implement to agree from the user, it just insight the information about the app task. if anyone know please share with me how can i create to agree from the user when first time app start, more help full if have any tutorials. Thanks

Comment: From your question, it's not clear to me what you want your app to do.

Comment: when the app start first time it should ask to accept EULA agreement from the userrs

Comment: I don't think that's something that Apple likes at all. When I download or buy an app from the App Store, I expect that it is covered by Apple's license and not by any other terms that you claim.

Comment: this what i got from apple review - Require that users agree to terms (EULA) and these terms must make it clear that there is no tolerance for objectionable content

Comment: I'm having the same issue with my social application because there is user-generated content. Am I really supposed to prompt a user to sign a EULA agreement aside from the TOS and Privacy already linked to at sign up?

Answer (score 0):

When you start your app, use `NSUserDefaults` to see whether there's a flag that says the agreement has been accepted.

If it's not there, present a modal view controller with your EULA.

If the user says they agree, use `NSUserDefaults` to set the flag.

Comment: Hi have you got any tutorial or any samples about this NSUserDefaults, tnx

Comment: Check the "More related items..." section of the NSUserDefaults documentation.  Apple lists **six** different sample applications that use it.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/